# How to write thanks to many people for different purposes

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I would like to add acknowledgement section in a paper. There are two groups of people who provided different sort of help. The acknowledgement looks like:

> I would like to thank X, Y, and Z for their feedback, and A, B, and C
>   for proofreading.

However, with real names, the actual sentence look too long. In addition, the two `and`s in `and A, B, and C` which do not seem right two me.

Are there any suggestions to improve it? i.e. would it look better to reformat it like:

> I would like to thank X, Y, and Z for their feedback. And A, B, and C
>   for proofreading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is nothing grammatically wrong with your sentences, your question is a matter of style. If you find the two lists of names lacking in style, you could make the acknowledgement more elaborate, by something like:"Feedback from X, Y and Z led to a clearer account, made even better by brilliant proofreading by A, B and C."